# Module.css not loading styles NEXT js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm trying apply module.css to one of my components according to this guide https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/layout-component.

```
/*/components/Livestream/App.js*/

import styles from './App.module.css';
...
return (
<div className={styles.container}>
 <main>
    <div className='live-stream'>
...
export default App;

/*/components/Livestream/App.module.css*/

.container main {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container main .live-stream {
  background-color: #000615;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However only the **main** tag gets the css styling and not the class **live-stream**:

[image: OnlyMainCSS]

[image: NotLiveStreamClass]

Comment: Ok I just tried it myself.
I think that you cannot do it this way, looks like the module.css doesn't recognize or cannot override a external css (? I'm writting this because module.css has only a local scope so...)


Maybe you should give your .live-stream a class inside your css module

Comment: But the only place on the whole project that a css references .live-stream is on App.module.css, I also tried chaging the main element to a div with class 'main' and the changes were not picked up anymore. Its like main tag works but not class names.

Answer (score 1):

Solved like :

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  <main>
    <div className={styles.liveStream}>

 #CSS
.container main .liveStream {
 // styles
 }
```